# Pass class as parameter with extension check in Java

Tags: java, class, generics

I want to pass a class as parameter to a method and access a static variable from it, but i want to be sure the class extends MyClass, how can i achieve it? is it possible?

something like:

```
public String getClassTag(Class myClass) {
     //if myClass extends MyClass
     return ((MyClass)myClass).TAG;
}
```

**Update** 
Sorry i think i explained it very bad.
Basically i have a method like the one shown above, i also have more classes extending MyClass and each of them "override" the parameter TAG which is a field of MyClass. i want to access this parameter but obviously i cannot access like `MyClass.TAG` because it won't be initialize and will not contain the value i need.

Comment: You want to make sure a class is an instance of `MyClass`? Maybe you want to pass an object, not a class?

Comment: A class should be an instance? How should that work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be dependent on the type of the parameter when you want to access a `static` method/member from a **certain** class. Just do something like:

```
public void someMethod(SomeClass class) {
    SomeClass.staticMethod(); //or SomeClass.staticMember;
}
```

I saw your update. I don't think you need to have theae `TAG` members static. Instead, you can override a getter that retrieves the TAG value from the current class. This way you'll achive flexibility. In this case, the method should be something like:

```
public void someMethod(SomeClass arg) {
    arg.getTag();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare this method signature:

```
void myMethod(Class<? extends MyClass> klass) {
   klass.getField("TAG").get(null);
}
```

but this limits the ways you acquire the `klass` instance which you pass in. Class literals and `myObject.getClass()` would work, for example, because enough type information is present at compile time.

The runtime variant of the type check would be

```
if (!MyClass.class.isAssignableFrom(klass))
   throw new ClassCastException("Argument not assignment-compatible with MyClass");
```

Comment: I will give it a try if it works for me is the best answer and the only right actually.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really a `Class<?>` object do you have as a parameter or do you have an instance of a MyClass-extending class ? If the latter you could use the following code:

```
public <E extends MyClass> String getClassTag(E myClass) {
     return myClass.TAG;
}
```

If only can provide a `Class<?>` object the following code maybe works, but you have to access the field via Reflection (which is much more complicated ;) )

```
public <E extends MyClass> String getClassTag(Class<E> myClass) {
     ...
     myClass.getField("TAG");
     ...
}
```

Comment: Note that Eclipse will be remarking that a static field should be accessed in a static way, which is indeed the better way. So you should consider refactoring your code like @kocko mentioned.